# Pymongo find_one_and_update returning null (Azure Cosmos DB)

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, pymongo, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

This behaviour is observed with both pymongo and the C# .NET version of the mongo driver.

We have an Azure Cosmos DB instance, running server version Mongo 4.0. We have a collection with circa 80,000 records, and when we run `find_one_and_update` in a single thread, we always get a document returned. For example, if we run a do loop 1000 times, we'll update and find 1000 documents.

The update we are running is similar to a lock/reservation process - we do not want to "upsert" documents if no filter matches. We are aware that `find_one_and_update` returns null after an upsert if you request the original document, but this is not what we are after.

When we run this across threads (either threaded in a single app or by just running 2 instances of the program) `find_one_and_update` returns `null` about 20% of the time. Note, it does **not** raise an exception (we would be happy receiving a 16500 (rate limit) error - but getting `null` back implies there are no more documents to find - which is indistinguishable from there *genuinely* being no documents left.

I suspect Cosmos might be to blame here, rather than the mongo emulator. I also fear a silent timeout, but the "maxTimeMS" modification below made zero difference.

Here is the code I am running, it's fairly simple:

```
def reserve_work():
    cutoff_date = datetime.now(timezone.utc) - timedelta(minutes=20)
    filter = {"Project": "proj", "Folder": "mc", "Complete": False, "$or": [{"LockedDate" : None}, {"LockedDate": {"$lt": cutoff_date}}]}
    update = {"$set": {"LockedDate": datetime.now(timezone.utc)}}
    sort = [("TargetCompletionDate", pymongo.ASCENDING)]

    try:
        result = mydb["capture-work"].find_one_and_update(filter, update, sort=sort, maxTimeMS=10000 )
    
        if result is None:
            logger.info("Null returned")
            return True
        else:
            logger.info("Got result")
            return False
    except:
        logger.info("Got exception")
    
    return None
```

Comment: I have just added 2 different "Folder" values: "mc" and "mc2" - and when I run 2 threads, I get no `null` responses returned!

It looks like a Cosmos record locking/write concern issue, but I don't know how to prove this.

Still, I believe the Cosmos driver should be returning some form of exception rather than `null`

Comment: The % nulls returned is equal to the number of threads, so 2 threads = 20% nulls, 3 threads = 30% nulls etc. This is proving, in my mind, that find_one_and_update is not thread safe inside cosmos - one thread is winning and updating the record, and the other threads are failing and being given "null" as the record when really they should fail with some form of exception. We are being charged RUs for these nulls too, and having to resubmit the query

Answer (score 0):

This is a Cosmos issue, in the way it emulates the MongoDB API. Microsoft are working on a fix, due to be released June/July 2021.

Find One And Update is meant to move onto the next record in the filter if the document has changed since the filter was run (which it will be if other threads are also running the same function) - however Cosmos is just aborting when it detects the first record in the list has changed.